# Spark SQL where clause with Dates between not returning data though it has data for that dates

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I am expecting the ABC_df to display/return data in my databricks notebook. but its not returning the data though there is data for the period '2019-02-24' AND '2019-03-31'
I tried using

```sql
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(E.EVENT_TIME_UTC,'yyyy-MM-dd') BETWEEN '2019-02-24' AND '2019-03-31'
```

where condition it works fine and successfully returns the data

But I want to implement a dynamic parameter,So I am using below options but data is not returning

```sql
BETWEEN CAST('{IterStartLagDatetime}' AS STRING) AND CAST('{IterEndDatetime}' AS STRING)
BETWEEN to_date('{IterStartLagDatetime}','yyyy-MM-dd') AND to_date('{IterEndDatetime}','yyyy-MM-dd')
BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT('{IterStartLagDatetime}','yyyy-MM-dd') AND DATE_FORMAT('{IterEndDatetime}','yyyy-MM-dd')
```

complete code is listed above. please help me with any other possible solutions

```
%python
BatchInsert_StartYear = 2019
BatchInsert_EndYear = 2019
while (BatchInsert_StartYear <= BatchInsert_EndYear):
print(BatchInsert_StartYear)
MonthCount = 1
while (MonthCount < 13):
if(MonthCount < 12):  
IterEndDatetime = right('00'+ str(MonthCount+1),2)+'-01-'+ str(BatchInsert_StartYear)
IterEndDatetime = datetime.strptime(IterEndDatetime,'%m-%d-%Y')+ timedelta(days=-1)
IterEndDatetime = IterEndDatetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
print(IterEndDatetime)
IterStartDatetime = right('00'+ str(MonthCount),2)+'-01-'+ str(BatchInsert_StartYear)
IterStartLagDatetime = datetime.strptime(IterStartDatetime,'%m-%d-%Y')+ timedelta(days=-5)
IterStartDatetime = datetime.strptime(IterStartDatetime,'%m-%d-%Y').strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
print(IterStartDatetime)
    
IterStartLagDatetime = IterStartLagDatetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
print(IterStartLagDatetime)
else:
IterEndDatetime = right('00'+ str(1),2)+'-01-'+ str(BatchInsert_StartYear+1)
IterEndDatetime = datetime.strptime(IterEndDatetime,'%m-%d-%Y')+ timedelta(days=-1)
IterEndDatetime = IterEndDatetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
print(IterEndDatetime)
IterStartDatetime = right('00'+ str(MonthCount),2)+'-01-'+ str(BatchInsert_StartYear)
IterStartLagDatetime = datetime.strptime(IterStartDatetime,'%m-%d-%Y')+ timedelta(days=-5)
IterStartDatetime = datetime.strptime(IterStartDatetime,'%m-%d-%Y').strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
print(IterStartDatetime)
IterStartLagDatetime = IterStartLagDatetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
print(IterStartLagDatetime)
ABC_df = spark.sql('''
SELECT *
FROM Temp_HISTORICAL_SWIPE_DETAILS E
BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT('{IterStartLagDatetime}','yyyy-MM-dd') AND DATE_FORMAT('{IterEndDatetime}','yyyy-MM-dd')
''')
ABC_df.show()
```

Comment: Are you getting any error or is it not returning the desired results? Can you also edit the code to give properly indented code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the given code, I can see that you are trying to reference variables directly inside `spark.sql()` directly. Look at the following demonstration to understand how to use variables inside the query (string).

- I have the following data in my table `demo3` as an example.

[image]

- When I use a similar query as yours, it returns one record as shown below:

```
%sql

select * from demo3 WHERE DATE_FORMAT(dt,'yyyy-MM-dd') BETWEEN '2019-02-24' AND '2019-03-31'
```

[image]

- Now let's say you want to use variables inside this query (you have created these date variables directly, but I have given the value directly for demonstration).
- If I give the query same as yours, we will not get desired. You can use another variable `query` to check what query is getting executed and then give that `query` variable

```
startdate='2019-02-24'
enddate='2019-03-31'

query = '''select * from demo3 WHERE DATE_FORMAT(dt,'yyyy-MM-dd') BETWEEN '{startdate}' AND '{enddate}' '''
print(query)
df = spark.sql(query)
df.show()
```

[image]

- You can use **f-strings** in python strings to reference the variables inside strings. So, giving query as below would give the desired result.

```
startdate='2019-02-24'
enddate='2019-03-31'

#use f"...{variable}..." to reference variables.
query = f'''select * from demo3 WHERE DATE_FORMAT(dt,'yyyy-MM-dd') BETWEEN '{startdate}' AND '{enddate}' '''
print(query)
df = spark.sql(query)
df.show()
```

[image]